# How to set return value of method of mock.patch result?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a test function which is getting a mocked class via a `@mock.patch` decorator.  Within the function, I want to force a return value of one of the method (which is needed for the test to succeed) as well as make assertions on another of the methods; these methods are exercised by calling a free function in the class's module.

Example module bla.py:

```
class Tool:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = list()

    def m1(self, val):
        self.items.append(val)

    def act(self):
        return len(self.items)


def exercise_tool():
    toolio = Tool()

    for i in range(2):
        toolio.m1(i)

    return toolio.act() <= 2
```

and its test:

```
from unittest import mock

import bla

@mock.patch("bla.Tool")
def test_exercise_tool(mtool):
    mtool.act.return_value = 3
    assert not bla.exercise_tool()  # verify the mocked return value
    mtool.m1.assert_was_called()
```

The test fails with `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'int'`.

So how do I get this test to pass?

Comment: You need to mock the _instance_ of `Tool`, e.g. `mtool.return_value.act.return_value = 3`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen thanks, that's the wrinkle I was seeking. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help, but this has been answered many times, so I don't think an answer will help anyone else.